Trying out gemini-1.5-flash on Jupyter Notebook
I am new to Stack Overflow. Looking forward to everyone's guidance.
I am trying to run Gemini-1.5-flash on my desktop's Jupyter Notebook which is running Python. I managed to get the following code to run properly on Google Colab but was not able to run the same on my Jupyter Notebook.
I am using Jupyter Notebook, the version of the notebook server is: 6.4.8
The server is running on this version of Python: Python 3.8.19 (default, Mar 20 2024, 19:55:45) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Any suggestions or assistance will be much appreciated!
My code:
import google.generativeai as genai

from getpass import getpass
GEMINI_API_KEY = getpass("Enter your API Key:")

genai.configure(api_key=GEMINI_API_KEY)

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash")

This is the error message I got on the last line of code:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21292\1593583074.py in <module>
----> 1 model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash")

AttributeError: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'GenerativeModel'


That's probably just because of a name issue, like a typo.

As shared in the question, the same code was able to be run on Google Colab notebook in Google Drive, but was unable to be run on Jupyter Notebook. Hence it is unlikely that it is a typo. Please highlight the specific typo if I am mistaken. Thanks.

Your Python and Jupyter are quite old, especially the Python. I doubt Google Colab is using that old of Python. So you are comparing very different things as how up-to-date other things are will be determined by that key component. However, I would try with the old Python a bit more for now, or at least only update to 3.10, as someone wanted older Python as a recommendation here. Albeit two versions after what you are trying. Overall your post seems a duplicate of ...

 'Gemini AI error - "AttributeError: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'GenerativeModel'"' here and this issue report here. You should try those solutions and then only make a new post where you describe in detail what you did that those suggested that didn't help.
